# display result as 1 row in transposed/pivoted result of sub query in SQL Compact edition

Tags: pivot, sql-server-ce-3.5

I have a table `MonitorLocationDetails` which looks like below

```
lid LoclColumn  LocDescription
1   MP1         MP-1 descr
2   MP2         MP-2 descr
3   MainGate    Main Gate descr
```

I should get the rows of `LocDescription` and transpose it like pivot in sql server other versions. PIVOT not available in sql compact versions.
The Pivoting should be based on the result of a sub query

```
SELECT LocColumn,LocDescription 
FROM MonitorLocationDetails 
WHERE LocColumn IN ('MP1','MP2','MainGate')
```

This works ok.

I have so far :

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    (CASE WHEN P.LocColumn = 'MP1' THEN P.LocDescription ELSE '' END), 
    (CASE WHEN P.LocColumn = 'MainGate' THEN P.LocDescription ELSE '' END), 
    (CASE WHEN P.LocColumn = 'MP2' THEN P.LocDescription ELSE '' END) 
FROM (
    SELECT LocColumn,LocDescription 
    FROM MonitorLocationDetails 
    WHERE LocColumn IN ('MP1','MP2','MainGate')
) P
```

which yields:

```
column1     column2     column3
                        MP-2 descr
            Main Gate desc  
MP-1 descr
```

empty spaces even with DISTINCT used.. i did not give names for columns, cause i need the result just as follows in 1 row

```
MP-1 descr   Main Gate descr    MP-2 descr
```

Any one would you please assist?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're close. You just have to put `MAX` before your `CASE expression`.

```
SELECT 
    MAX(CASE WHEN P.LocColumn = 'MP1' THEN P.LocDescription ELSE '' END), 
    MAX(CASE WHEN P.LocColumn = 'MainGate' THEN P.LocDescription ELSE '' END), 
    MAX(CASE WHEN P.LocColumn = 'MP2' THEN P.LocDescription ELSE '' END) 
FROM (
    SELECT LocColumn,LocDescription 
    FROM MonitorLocationDetails 
    WHERE LocColumn IN ('MP1','MP2','MainGate')
) P
```

---

You could also simplify your query:

```
;WITH MonitorLocationDetails(lid, LocColumn, LocDescription) AS(
    SELECT 1, 'MP1', 'MP-1 Descr' UNION ALL
    SELECT 2, 'MP2', 'MP-2 Descr' UNION ALL
    SELECT 3, 'MainGate', 'MainGate Descr'
)
SELECT
    MAX(CASE WHEN LocColumn = 'MP1' THEN LocDescription ELSE '' END), 
    MAX(CASE WHEN LocColumn = 'MainGate' THEN LocDescription ELSE '' END), 
    MAX(CASE WHEN LocColumn = 'MP2' THEN LocDescription ELSE '' END) 
FROM MonitorLocationDetails 
WHERE LocColumn IN ('MP1','MP2','MainGate')
```

Comment: your simplified one looks good, but gives me blank result. I can't yet upvote cause of not enough reputations. will mark it as answer.. but still curious about the 2nd sql by you

Comment: Really? Try again, I've added sample data this time.

Comment: got it.. i mean works even without the sample. It was just the extra spaces which made the sql SDF viewer not recognizing it. so we dont even need to use DISTINCT.